# How to put text on either side of a div html5

Tags: css, html

I have been trying to place some text on both side of a div but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong because no matter what I try it won't work.

What I want to achieve is:
[image]

Below is what I have tried

```
I am <div>I will be adding a scale here</div> old
<div>I am</div> <div>I will be adding a scale here</div> <div>old</div>]
```

but it returns

[image]

I have managed to reached the desired with the following code, however I want to do this using divs only and not inputs, labels and span.

```html
<span>Good</span>
<input type="range" id="weight" min="0" value="0" max="3" step="1" list="volsettings">
<span>Bad</span>
<datalist id="volsettings">
  <option>0</option>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  </datalist>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lw155sx9/

If possible, I rather not using any css. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without using css, you could just use a simple table. This is considered bad practice though. Why would you not want to use css?

Comment: _"I rather not using any css"_ Why not?

Comment: That's happening because `div` has `display: block`. You need to use a `span`, which has `display: inline-block`. e.g. `I am <span>I will be adding a scale here</span> old`

Comment: @j08691 I wouldn't mind using it if its the only way to achieve this but I have a lot of CSS code written already and I am trying to minimise it where possible because I am still learning web development and I want to see what can and can't be done with only HTML5

Comment: For anyone who comes across this and wants to use CSS, I would strongly suggest understanding all of the concepts that bootstrap has to offer here: http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: @Adam You do understand that saying : I want an inline behavior but I don't want to use an inline element and I don't want to use a block element styled to have an inline behavior to achieve it... well, it sounds a bit insane ?

Comment: Hi, I am new to web development - what do you mean by inline elements and block elements. Are these things like span?

Comment: @Adam You should read a bit :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

Basically, a block element will occupy the entire width of the parent element, the inline element won't.
So, when you say, I want a div (block element) to be next to another div, you go against their normal behavior, so you have to use css or to use inline element.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of flexbox with minimal changes and css styles.

Here is what you could do.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>I am</div>
  <div>I will be adding a scale here</div>
  <div>old</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<span>`, which is is an inline type of `<div>`. But if you really need an inline div there, create a class for it and assign it to the divs:

CSS:

```
.display-inline {display: inline;}
```

HTML:

```
I am <div class="display-inline">I will be adding a scale here</div> old
```

If you want the inline divs to display content other than text, like bigger images, then you might want to use `inline-block` instead:

```
.display-inline-block {display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to change them all the span's or use css and change the div's to `display: inline` using css. Then set a with on each div.

Also set `text-align: center` on the parent div.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Wrap a div around another div, the give the inner div `display:inline-block;` and the outer div `:before` and `:after` pseudo selectors to display the text on both sides of the inner div, then call it day. ;-)

#### SNIPPET

```css
.line {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 255, .5), rgba(0, 0, 255, 1), rgba(0, 0, 255, .5));
  height: 100%;
  width: 60vw;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.box {
  height: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.box:before {
  content: 'BEFORE';
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.box:after {
  content: 'AFTER';
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='line'></div>
</div>
```